# Reach the attributes of an input element in the template - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I would like to reach the attributes of an input element the way something like this:

```
<input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" id="salonName" data-ng-model="salon.name" ng-minlength=3 ng-maxlength=30 required/>
    This works: {{myForm.name.$viewValue}}
    This does not: {{myForm.name.id}}
    This does not too: {{myForm.name.ngMinlength}}
```

Comment: Here is the form: <form name="myForm">

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using simple directive, like:

**JS**

```
var fessmodule = angular.module('myModule', []);

fessmodule.controller('fessCntrl', function ($scope) {});
fessmodule.$inject = ['$scope'];

fessmodule.directive("myDirective", function () {
            return function(scope, element, attrs) {                               
                scope.name = attrs['name']; 
                scope.type = attrs['type'];
                scope.class = attrs['class'];
                scope.id = attrs['id'];
                scope.ngMinlength = attrs['ngMinlength'];
                scope.ngMaxlength = attrs['ngMaxlength'];
                scope.ngModel = attrs['ngModel'];
                scope.required = attrs['required'];                
            };
    });
```

Add directive to HTML:

```
<input my-directive
            name="name"
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
           id="salonName"
           data-ng-model="salon.name"
           ng-minlength=3
           ng-maxlength=30
           required/>

    <pre> Name: {{name}}</pre>
    <pre> type: {{type}}</pre>
    <pre> class: {{class}}</pre>
    <pre> ngMinlength: {{ngMinlength}}</pre>
    <pre> ngMaxlength: {{ngMaxlength}}</pre>
    <pre> ngModel: {{ngModel}}</pre>
    <pre> required: {{required}}</pre>
```

Demo [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/666/)